# Как перейти с одной функции на другую не через bot.register_next_step_handler?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, разработка-игр, бот, telebot

Делаю игру для телеграм бота. Но после того как бот отправляет правила он ожидает от меня сообщения, чтобы  затем перейти на функцию `step`. Вопрос: можно ли сделать так, чтобы после отправки правил игры выполнилась функция `step`, но без требования отправки сообщения (чего требует `bot.register_next_step_handler`). Т.е. чтобы осуществился переход с одной функции на другую без причины.

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "готов")
def preparing(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отлично! Игра начинается.')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Правила батла.')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, step)

def step(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Варианты ходов 1/2/3')
    choice = message.text
    if choice == '1':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы сделали действие 1')
    elif choice == '2':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы сделали действие 2')
    elif choice == '3':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы сделали действие 3')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите действие 1/2/3')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, step)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто вызови функцию `step(message)`

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "готов")
def preparing(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отлично! Игра начинается.')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Правила батла.')
    step(message)
```